# Android OpenGL Tracer: Failed due to NumberFormatException?

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, android-ndk

Has anyone had the Android Studio OpenGL Tracer start failing to read any trace files it produces, stating:

```
 Failed to create the part's controls
```

And when the Details button is pressed:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
```

I'm getting this issue against multiple devices -- and I really need GL tracing to work here.

Comment: This is not the app -- as others can trace GL from the same app.  I can also view traces they obtain on the machine where I cannot trace.

It thus seems like something is remiss with my Android Studio, Android SDK, or some such.  Unfortunately trying to reinstall the Android Device Monitor app (by deleting it and switching tooling versions in the SDK manager) does not fix the problem.

It's unclear where the problem actually resides.

Comment: Same problem here, no idea why. What a absolute steaming pile of crap Android's tooling is.

Comment: I'd not be that harsh on the tooling at large.

That said, there are certainly "nooks and crannies" of functionality that are absolutely critical yet are currently effectively or entirely unusable, e.g. detailed GL debugging and profiling and native heap examination.

Comment: But they've had so many years to get it at least working, if not brilliantly.  XCode's Instruments seem light years ahead of anything Android has, and are likely to remain so.